# Parallel request from rails controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, http, response

I have a usecase where when an action of the controller is called, it triggers 3 http request to other urls. I need to parse the response of those requests , combine them and then render the view. How do I trigger 3 request in parallel and not sequentially so that it saves time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Typhoes](https://github.com/typhoeus) for handling parallel calls.

Jump to [making parallel calls](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus#making-parallel-requests) section to see how you can make parallel calls.

Example

```
 # Assume these were your two HTTP calls
 first_request = Typhoes::Request.new('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=2')
 second_request = Typhoes::Request.new('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=3')

 # Initialize a Hydra queue (this holds typhoes requests)
 hydra = Typhoeus::Hydra.hydra
 hydra.queue [first_request, second_request]
 hydra.run # this triggers the calls

 # Getting response, once the run is complete

 first_request.response 
 second_request.response
```